# how to use baked fire smoke fluid data in scripting

Tags: scripting, physics, import, cache

i am creating a fire and smoke simulation using the bpy scripting , to avoid the baking fluid again and again , i baked the fluid manually in another blend file with modular and openvdb , now i want to use this baked data here in scripting